# If $u(x,y)$ is harmonic, how do I show that $u(z(x,y),w(x,y))$ is harmonic?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Suppose that $u(x,y)$ is an harmonic function. Consider the transformation:
>
> \begin{align}
> z &= c + x\cos\theta + y\sin\theta, \\
> w &= d - x\sin\theta + y\cos\theta,
> \end{align}
> where $d$, $c$, and $\theta$ are constants
>
> Show that $u(z,w)$ is also an harmonic function ($u_{zz}+u_{ww}=0$).

It seems pretty obvious, but I am really struggling to find a way to show that $u(z,w)$ solves the equation.

Comment: Since $u(x,y)$ satisfies $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$, then of course $u(z,w)$ satisfies $u_{zz}+u_{ww}=0$.  That cannot be what you are really asking, is it?

Comment: it is, I know it is obvious but how do you prove it?

Comment: You don't have to prove anything.  You've assumed $u(x,y)$ satisfies $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$.  The arguments are just labels.  $u(a,b)$ satisfies $u_{aa}+u_{bb}=0$ and $u(\text{apples}, \text{oranges})$ satisfies $u_{\text{apples}\,\text{apples}}+u_{\text{oranges}\,\text{oranges}}=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is -

1. Solve for $x,y$ in terms of $z,w$
2. As $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}$, write $u_{zz} + u_{ww} $ in terms of $x,y$.

You should then have your answer.